# Theater Seat Image (Seat Status)

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I was wondering if it would be a good idea to store the dimensions of the image in the db in the table where i will be storing the path.

OR -

Should it be better just to check this at run-time and then put those values in a variable and calculate everything at run-time.

OR -

Would it be better to do this through MSSQL.

Also to better explain.

I have an equation which is using image height, image width, row,column to position the seats also there will be the factor of spacing in this equation so that it will come out perfectly.

Hope that this is understandable.

Comment: ummm, what are you doing? Are you placing (or trying to place) seat images in an area such that all the seats fits into it? So, basically you are placing a `MxN` area with `AxB` dimension chairs -- `A` and `B` vary based on chairs you choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enzero,

Hmmm, it's really impossible to answer that question ACURRATELY without more information; but in general, it's a good idea to keep your metadata *with* your data... and metadata which can be worked-out "on the fly" generally should be, to avert any future headaches with the metadata getting out of sync.

An image size is a strange thing to want to store... it's in the image-file itself, surely. What format is the image? Or am I missing something?

Cheers. Keith.

---

**EDIT:**

After a bit of discussion back-and-forth, Enzero says he'll try this approach:

Store the image itself as a BLOB (not just the path to a file containing the image) and it's height & width (etc) in the seat_status table. When the application starts-up it will load the seat_status's into a cache, for fast reference thereafter.

Cheers. Keith.

PS: You're welcome Enzero... happy to be of service.

Comment: Well sorry its just that i wasn't sure how to explain. Let me try to rephrase. I have an equation which is using image height, image width, row,column to position the seats also there will be the factor of spacing in this equation so that it will come out perfectly.

Comment: Do you have the images loaded at the point where you need to run through that equation?

Comment: No everything will be loaded in the OnInit and calculated accordingly.

Comment: OK, so there's ONE image, and it's static, right? If that image changes your program (or atleast the seat display) is totally stuffed... so I'd store the image properties in a properties file, along with the image-file-path... keeping everything together, and making them equally easy/hard to change (depending on how you look at it;-).

Comment: Obviously there isn't one image there is empty,reserved,booked at least for now unless i come up with something else

Comment: "Booked" is an attribute of each SEAT, surely... not the theatre, and you "surely" have one image of the theatre, which is a "constant", and then you overlay that image with "state information"... or are you generating a different image, with say red seats are booked; and gold for available first-class; and green for avialable cheap seats. What are you trying to DO? Never mind how... what effect do you want?

Comment: There is no image of the theater. I was going to try to do it with image buttons and positioning. Then each location according to status or type will load an image accordingly.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes a bit more sense... so you want to store an image and it's attributes in a seat_type table? If so I'd just store the image (as a blob) and it's metadata (for QUICK retrieval) in the database table. No way would I store an image for every single booking!

Comment: No not for every single booking. That would truly be crazy i made a table seat_status and another table seatstatus_image in that table i was going to store the path and dimensions to be used in the formula that was my question i thought it was quite understandable.

Comment: Well now it is... so don't worry about it: and yes, I'd store the image itself as a BLOB (not just the path to a file containing the image) and it's height & width (etc) in the seat_status table. When the application starts up it would load-up the seat_status's. That'll do fine, I expect. Quick and easy to code.

Comment: Well then thanks for you time i can't exactly accept your answer since its a comment unless you would like to re-post the answer. Also i never used blobs before i'll check it out.

Comment: I posted that answer as an edit to my answer. You're welcome. Keith. I suggest you wait a couple of days before accepting this answer... someone else may have a better idea!

Comment: Ok then will do although i doubt lets see though.